# 'it didn't happen until afterward" happened later or didn't happen continuously?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

> 'it didn't happen until afterward"

After reading this sentence, it's not certain to interpret it as intended because "not until A" means something happened after A.

The above sentence means happened or didn't happen?

Comment: It did happen, after something else happened;.

Comment: Thx. Can I approximately assume how long period it took until "it happend"? because I feel "until afterwards" is vague. When do you usually use this expression "until afterwards"?

Comment: We use an expression like 'B didn't happen until after A' when the point is that B happened after A, and the amount of time is not important or relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
(timeline)

--------A---------B-------
--------AB----------------
--------A[---afterwards---]
```

Did B happen before A? No, it didn't happen until *afterwards* (the BrE version of *afterward*).

*afterwards* refers to the time after A happened.

Comment: If I say "it did happen afterwards",  what could be difference?

Comment: Either way, B did happen and it happened after A. I think the original sentence has a stronger stress on the relationship between A and B (and, perhaps, on the impact A had on B)